# abstract has no column named

Tags: python, django

I use Django2.0.5+Python3.6.I defined two classes:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    isMale = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    mail = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __str(self):
        return self.name


class User(Person):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    date_joined = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = False
    def __str(self):
        return self.department + "'s " + self.name
```

Then,I run

```
   python manage.py makemigrations
   python manage.py migrate
```

Though sqlmigrate command,I can see:

```
migrations.CreateModel(
            name='User',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('isMale', models.BooleanField(default=True)),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=32)),
                ('age', models.IntegerField()),
                ('mail', models.CharField(max_length=64)),
                ('phone', models.CharField(max_length=32)),
                ('address', models.CharField(max_length=32)),
                ('username', models.CharField(max_length=64)),
                ('password', models.CharField(max_length=64)),
                ('department', models.CharField(max_length=64)),
                ('date_joined', models.DateField()),
            ],
            options={
                'abstract': False,
            },
        ),


class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

But in the shell,if I run such commands:

```
p = User(username="",password="",department="",isMale=True,name="",age=1,mail="",phone="",date_joined=timezone.now())
 p.save()
```

I get this:
**django.db.utils.OperationalError: table vsoa_user has no column named isMale**

.But in sqlmigrate command，I can the "isMale" field in the "User". If I delete "abstract=True" from Person ,this error disappear.

I have read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/,but that is no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude, I tried with same code and it worked for me. I added an object from admin and it was added. Only thing I changed was the name of user to usera since i had already an user model. Maybe you are importing auth.User in code and thats causing the clash?

```
class Person(models.Model):
    isMale = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    mail = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Usera(Person):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    date_joined = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = False
    def __str__(self):
        return self.department + "'s " + self.name

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *
# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Usera)
```

Comment: thanks,I create a new project and redo the above operation,it works.